# How can I stop Git from generating .new files?

Tags: git, git-extensions

I am using Git Extensions.  When I do a Push to a remote, I get files and directories with a .new extension.  How can I keep Git or Git Extensions from generating these files?

I have researched git and .new extension, but I have not found anything about it on Google or StackOverflow.

Comment: Git doesn’t generate these files. I bet they’re so git can see empty directories.

Comment: GitExtensions doesn't generate any new file either.
If you believe otherwise, please reach us at https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions/issues